# Adding a pattern fill to a black and white column graph in Highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts

I have come across the following guide for adding pattern fills for https://jkunst.com/highcharter/articles/modules.html

I would like to have the first column as a solid column and then patterns added to the remaining three columns

With the first set of code i get the following error <Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :  'options' must be a fully named list, or have no names (NULL)>
With the second set of code i get a title, the x axis title and the legend key with no data on the graph
Is there an error in my code that i have missed?

'''

```
Column_with_stripe<-highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type ="column") %>%
  hc_title(text = "A") %>%
  hc_add_dependency("modules/pattern-fill.js") %>% 
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_tufte()) %>% 
  hc_legend(align = "Right", verticalAlign = "top", floating = TRUE,borderRadius = 10 , backgroundColor = "white" , borderWidth = 1, layout = "vertical", x=50, y =-5)%>% 
  hc_legend(enabled = TRUE) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = c('Day 1-7', 'Day 7-14', 'Day 14-21', 'Day 21-28', 'Day 28-35', 'Day 35-42'), tickmarkPlacement = "on") %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Catch of fly per week")) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(line = list (datalabels = list(emabled = TRUE), enableMouseTracking = FALSE))%>%
  hc_plotOptions(area = list(fillColor = list(pattern = list(path = list(d = 'M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11',strokeWidth = 3),width = 10,height = 10,opacity = 0.4))))%>%
  hc_series(list (name = "Var1", data = c(5,8,25,10,28,15)),
        list (name = "Var2", data = c(4,5,1,6,4,3),color= 'white',fillColor = list(pattern = list(color='black')),
        list (name = "Var3", data = c(0,35,18,38,19,18),color= 'white',fillColor = list(pattern = list(color='black')),
        list (name = "Var4", data = c(6,8,29,52,33,48),color= 'white',fillColor = list(pattern = list(color='black'))))))
Column_with_stripe
```

'''

```
Column_with_stripe_2 <-highchart() %>%hc_chart(type ="column") %>%
  hc_title(text = "A") %>%
  hc_add_dependency("modules/pattern-fill.js") %>% 
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_tufte()) %>% 
  hc_legend(align = "Right", verticalAlign = "top", floating = TRUE,borderRadius = 10 , backgroundColor = "white" , borderWidth = 1, layout = "vertical", x=50, y =-5)%>% 
  hc_plotOptions(
    area = list(fillColor = list(pattern = list(path = list(d = 'M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11',strokeWidth = 3),width = 10,height = 10,opacity = 0.4))))%>%
  hc_legend(enabled = TRUE) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = c('Day 1-7', 'Day 7-14', 'Day 14-21', 'Day 21-28', 'Day 28-35', 'Day 35-42'), tickmarkPlacement = "on") %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Catch of fly per week")) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(line = list (datalabels = list(emabled = TRUE), enableMouseTracking = FALSE))%>%
  hc_add_series(list (name = "Var1", data = c(5,8,25,10,28,15))%>%
  hc_add_series(list (name = "Var2", data = c(4,5,1,6,4,3), color= '#000',fillColor = list(pattern = list(color = '#000'))))%>%
  hc_add_series(list (name = "Var3", data = c(0,35,18,38,19,18), color= '#000',fillColor = list(pattern = list(color = '#000'))))%>%
  hc_add_series(list (name = "Var4", data = c(6,8,29,52,33,48), color= '#000',fillColor = list(pattern = list(color = '#000'))))
Column_with_stripe_2
```

Comment: Yes i have added data to my code

Comment: Yes i have got the same error with my first set of code, i have added a second set of code which contains my original error of a graph with no data appearing

Answer (score 1):

So, there might be a better way, but I looked at Highcharts documentation online and came up with the code posted below.

Link: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/pattern-fills

Code:

```
Column_with_stripe<-highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type ="column") %>%
  hc_title(text = "A") %>%
  hc_add_dependency("modules/pattern-fill.js") %>% 
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_tufte()) %>% 
  hc_legend(align = "Right", verticalAlign = "top", floating = TRUE,borderRadius = 10 , backgroundColor = "white" , borderWidth = 1, layout = "vertical", x=50, y =-5)%>% 
  hc_legend(enabled = TRUE) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = c('Day 1-7', 'Day 7-14', 'Day 14-21', 'Day 21-28', 'Day 28-35', 'Day 35-42'), tickmarkPlacement = "on") %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Catch of fly per week"))%>%
  hc_plotOptions(line = list (datalabels = list(emabled = TRUE), enableMouseTracking = FALSE)) %>%
  hc_series(list(name = "Var1", data = c(5,8,25,10,28,15), color=list(pattern=list(color="black")))) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "Var2", data = c(4,5,1,6,4,3),color= list(pattern=list(path='M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11', width=2, height=7, color='green')),fillColor = "transparent") %>%
  hc_add_series(name="Var3", data = c(0,35,18,38,19,18),color=list(pattern = list(path='M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11', width=5, height=5, color='#f00')), fillColor="transparent")
Column_with_stripe
```

Maybe this will get you closer to what you're looking for.

-nate